# German TV Schedule Display in a Large Table

Tags: gratis, scheduling

I am looking for a free tool, web-based or locally runnable on Windows, that displays the TV schedule for channels receivable in Germany throughout entire days **in a large table**.

There are plenty of websites that offer a German TV schedule, for example:

- [rtv](http://www.rtv.de/tv-programm/heute-im-tv.html)
- [Web.de](http://tv.web.de/#/)
- [Moviepilot](http://www.moviepilot.de/tv/fernsehprogramm)
- [tvprogramm24.cmo](http://www.tvprogramm24.com/)
- [TVSpielfilm](http://www.tvspielfilm.de/tv-programm/tv-sender/)
- [Klack.de](http://www.klack.de/fernsehprogramm/alles-auf-einen-blick/1/hauptsender.html)
- [TVInfo](http://www.tvinfo.de/fernsehprogramm)
- [TVToday](http://www.tvtoday.de/tv-programm)
- [TVMovie](http://www.tvmovie.de/tv/fernsehprogramm-heute-abend)
- [Hörzu](http://www.hoerzu.de/tv-programm/)
- ... and many more

All of these seem to have the problem that they only show a tiny excerpt of the TV schedule at a time:

- On most sites, only a few channels (~5) are visible at a time, and switching to other channels is solved via pagination through the table of channels. Instead, I would like to see either a custom (but unlimited in number!) set of channels, or the full available set of channels next to each other in a table. I do not mind scrolling.<sup>1</sup>
- On most sites, only a fraction of the day is visible at a time. The TV schedule gets fragmented into 2-hour-slots, or into "semantic" slots such as "noon", "afternoon", "evening", "night". Switching between these slots is, again, either done via pagination, or the individual slots have to be manually expanded and are usually hidden. Instead, I would like to see the entire day. Again, I do not mind scrolling.

So, essentially, I am looking for a tool or service that displays the whole TV schedule of an entire given day<sup>2</sup> in a large table, with one axis (preferably the horizontal) representing channels, and the other one times of the day. A bit like all the printed TV schedules do, just without the paper size restrictions and on a computer screen.

Some more features:

- Reordering/selecting a set of channels to show would be nice, but is not mandatory.
- If web-based, the tool should not be slowed down by endless script-based ads.
- Full-text search is desirable; if it is a web-based tool, the built-in browser text search should work.
- Additional info on shows (production year, episode name/number for series/...) is nice to have on demand, but not absolutely necessary.

<sup>1</sup>: The only one that goes into the right direction here is the [line-based view by TVInfo](http://www.tvinfo.de/tv-programm). However, it clings to the second behaviour I am criticizing, by showing only a tiny fraction of the day and requiring pagination to step through the day.

<sup>2</sup>: Some requirements that I hope are clear by common sense: The tool or service should be able to display the schedule for any given date I select (one day at a time is ok), and it should do so ahead of time (so I can pick shows that I'm going to watch).